# Integer (binary?) optimisation problem

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, operations-research, binary-programming

Refer to the table below where the numbers inside the cells represent profit.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
 & \text{Area A} & \text{Area B} & \text{Area C} & \text{Area D} \\ \hline
\text{Person 1} & 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{Person 2} & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{Person 3} & 4 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{Person 4} & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{Person 5} & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Given the constraint that a person can only be in one area at a time, I have a few questions:

- How to assign people to areas to maximise profit across all areas (Area A + Area B + Area C + Area D)?
- How to assign people to areas to maximise profit given a minimum profit constraint in each area (i.e. profit for Area Xi > 1)?

I am trying to model this in Excel, but happy to hear the theory behind it or be redirected to a more suitable exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You want to think of having 20 variables,
$$x_{A1}, \ldots, x_{A5}, \ldots, x_{D1}, \ldots, x_{D5}.$$
We have $x_{cd}$ taking value $1$ if person $d$ is at location $c$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now we can only have one person at each location so $\sum_{d} x_{cd} = 1$ for all $c \in \{A,B,C,D\}$, and each person can only be in one location so $\sum_{c} x_{cd} = 1$ for all $d \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  These are the constraints of the model.  Now we want to maximize the function
$\sum_{c,d} x_{cd} w_{cd}$
where $w_{cd}$ is the profit for having person $d$ in location $c$.

If you want to put a restriction of a minimum profit at each location, these go in as new constraints (one for each area).

You actually do not seem to have a requirement that only one person can be in each area, so the first type of constraint I mentioned above would be absent.  To maximize total profit is then easy: put each person where they make the most profit.  Techniques to solve in general are computational, I use Gurobi to solve these types of problems.